# Letters on a gas shut off/on valve meaning

Tags: gas

My question is what do the letters "P" and "L" stand for on a key shut off valve for gas logs?

Comment: Can you post a photo?

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of your gas logs system ?  'P' could stand for Purge and 'L' for Line.  A picture of the valve can be helpful - because it could be 'L P' on that handle - meaning Liquid Propane ..

Answer (score 1):

P is probably "pilot" for a standing pilot light - L is presumably for "Lit" or on. Typically you'll have off, pilot, and on for many gas appliances old enough to have a standing pilot light. Newer ones are prone to use some other sort of ignition for better efficiency when "off".

Depending on other letters or positions not mentioned, L might also be for "light" as in *start the full flame from the pilot at this position* - if it can turn up from there, you don't want to go past there until it is lit.